# How can I add a sound to a pickup?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

Alright, so I have recently gotten into Unity, I have gotten an assignment from school and I've decided to make a game that has a mirrors edge feel to is, but much more basic with a ball rolling around. problem is that the pickups I've tried to put around don't give any sound. I don't know how to fix it and I've tried looking up solutions but it just won't work. Can anyone help me?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Text countText;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizonal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizonal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("pickup"))
        {
            AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();            

            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText();           
        }
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no any call of `Play()` on `audio` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound won't play because you are **not** even calling the play function anywhere in your script. If the sound is attached to the-same GameObject the `Player_Controller`  script is attached to, you only have to do `AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();` in the Start function then do `audio.Play();` in the `OnTriggerEnter` function.

```
public float speed;
public Text countText;
private Rigidbody rb;
private int count;

AudioSource audio;
void Start()
{
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    SetCountText();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{

    float moveHorizonal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizonal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("pickup"))
    {
        audio.Play(); //Play it

        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText();
    }

}

void SetCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
}
```

Now, if the sound is attached to each GameObject you pick up, you should use `GetComponent` to get the `AudioSource` on that collider then play it.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("pickup"))
    {
        AudioSource audio = other.GetComponent<AudioSource>(); //Get audio from object
        audio.Play(); //Play it

        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.
Error CS0619 'Component.audio' is obsolete: 'Property audio has been deprecated. Use GetComponent<AudioSource>() instead. (UnityUpgradable)' (line 20)                                                                                        2.; expected (line 43)                                                                                      3. Property or indexer 'component.audio'cannot be assigned to -- it is read only (line 20)

Comment: Actually nevermind. i fixed the bugs, but the sound still wont play now. its copied exactly as you put it.

Comment: What is your Unity version? Which solution are you using from my answer(first or second)?

Comment: Unity 5.4.1f1 64Bit, but what i think is happening is that the audio is cut off before it even plays because the pickup is being disabled

Comment: My comment has two questions. What is the answer to to the last question?

Comment: Why not at least debug your code and tell us what is going on.  Is the code from `if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("pickup"))` being called? Put `Debug.Log("called....")` inside it to see what's going on. Also where is the audio source attached?

Comment: The audio source is put on the coin itself. and im not sure what you mean with debug. but i do know the code does get called. i put a tag on the coin that says pickup. if it wasnt being called the coins wouldnt dissapear.

Comment: "The audio source is put on the coin itself" That's the problem. Can you put the audio source to another GameObject that is not being disabled? Put it on the gameobject the `Player_Controller` script is attached to then use the first code in my answer.

Comment: Err.. i dont mean to sound stupid, since its only my second day using unity, but i cant seem to figure out how to put the audio source on another object.

Comment: Wait i dont mean the source, but i mean triggering that audio source when a coin is picked up

Comment: Dude this is a basic stuff. Watch a video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqauiquXFL4). Select that GameObject the `Player_Controller` is attached to, then go to Component->Audio->Audio Source. On the AudioSource, De-select "Play On Awake" then plug in the audio you want to play in the Audiclip slot from the AudioSource. That's it. The first code in my answer should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Im sorry i should have probably read up on stuff beforehand. thanks for helping me anyways.

Comment: It's ok. It's just that there many tutorials out there. Here is one from [Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials). Even if you are working on school projects, I suggest  you do one project(**Space Shooter tutorial**) from that link. It will teach you what you need to get started with Unity. They are easy too. Be honest, did you really solve this problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

Set the other to inactive

```
other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

and the sound will play.